# Retrive Total Comments by post ID using wpdb query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have two questions:

1. Count total number of comments (Without Post Author & Child Comments) by Post ID using wpbd query?
2. Get Last 3 comment author (without Post Author & Child Comments) by Post ID using wpdb query?

If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: What did you tried? Do you expect someone will do the job for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<?php $args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '0',
    'number' => '',
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    'status' => 'approve', //hold, approve, all
    'count' => true
);
$total_number_of_comments = get_comments( $args );
echo $total_number_of_comments;
?>
<?php $args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '0',
    'number' => '3',
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    'status' => 'approve', //hold, approve, all
    'count' => false
);
$last_three_comments = get_comments( $args );
print_r($last_three_comments);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. Its work fine. would you please help me another issu. last three comment author

Comment: Sometimes Last 3 comment author show duplicate. have you any idea to show comment author only one time?

Comment: I think you like this code :)
<pre><?php global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "select com2.comment_ID, com2.comment_author, com2.user_id, com2.comment_content, com2.comment_date
from $wpdb->comments as com2
WHERE com2.comment_ID IN (
select Max(com.comment_ID)
from $wpdb->comments as com
where com.comment_post_ID = 15
AND com.comment_approved = 1
GROUP BY com.comment_author_email
)
ORDER BY com2.comment_ID DESC
LIMIT 3" );
print_r($myrows);
?></pre>

Comment: avoid <pre> tag